# How do I get each distinct 'year' value out of a Django model with a datetime field?

Tags: python, django

I can successfully filter by a given year in my Django model, but I'm having trouble finding a way to list valid years so a user can access them.

I have a django model with a defined 'datetime' field, oh-so-originally named 'date'.  In my templates, I can successfully access the 'bar.date.date.year' field, so I know it exists, but when I try the following function...

```
blog_years=[]
for entry in blog_entries:
    if entry.date.date.year not in blog_years:
        blog_years.append(entry.date.date.year)
```

I'm told that "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'year'"

I can only assume I"m tripping over some aspect of Python I'm not familiar with, but I can't figure out what it is.  I'm quite certain it has to be syntactical, but past that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `.date` accesses a datetime object.

The second `.date` is accessing a method on datetime objects that returns a date object but not calling it (this step is unneccessary).

The last part (the way you wrote it) is trying to access the `year` attribute of the date method, instead of accessing the `year` attribute of the *result* of the date method call.

Correcting the code to see the difference, it would look like this...

```
blog_years=[]
for entry in blog_entries:
    if entry.date.date().year not in blog_years:
        blog_years.append(entry.date.date().year)
```

But what you should do is more like this...

```
blog_years=[]
for entry in blog_entries:
    if entry.date.year not in blog_years:
        blog_years.append(entry.date.year)
```

since datetime objects have the date attribute as well.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying -- and you're getting the answer check because you did a much better explanation of what's going on.  Just to check, you're saying that since blog_entry.date is a 'datetime' reference, I don't need to resolve that to a date reference with .date(), because datetime object understand .year just as well as a date object does?  (Almost like reverse inheritence...?  Or, more likely, date inherits 'year' from datetime, rather than having it declared locally)

Comment: @RonLugge Basically, yes. The datetime object is just a date object and a time object combined. If you use the date() method on it, you do not gain any extra functionality but lose the time methods.  I suggest reading some of [this](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and keeping in mind that entry.date _is_ a datetime object to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll definitely spend (more) time reading that reference this time around.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that `entry.date.date.year` works in your template, because the templating engine will attempt to call it as a method for you, since you can not use () to call functions in templates.

Comment: You could just use a `set`, and then you don't need to worry about checking if the year is already in the list.

Answer (score 25):

Django has an elegant and efficient way of doing this. You can check from their docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#dates 
But to go over it

```
Entry.objects.dates('pub_date', 'year')
```

This will bring out distinct year values in the query.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Not year values. It returns list of datetime.date objects

Answer (score 7):

if you are using postgres, you can do

```
  BlogEntry.objects.extra(select={"year": "EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM date)"}).distinct().values_list("year", flat=True)
```

Comment: This is very performant, compared to all the other approaches which evaluate the querysets. But if you use .extra() you should keep in mind that the Django core team [plans to deprecate this function sometime in the future](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

Comment: instead of deprecated extra you can use RawSQL `Model.objects
        .annotate(year=RawSQL('EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)', []))
        .values_list('year', flat=True)
        .distinct()`

Comment: Remember to call `.order_by()` on your queryset as well, as it's common for model's to have default sort orders, and that may add some joins and silently break the distinct.

Answer (score 5):

A Python `set` does not allow duplicates, so if you wanted a list of distinct years:

`blog_years = list(set([entry.date.year for entry in blog_entries]))`

Or, you could use [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

`blog_years = blog_entries.distinct(entry__date__year).values(entry__date__year)`

Of course, adjust the above based on your model.

Comment: To get list must be used `values_list('entry__date__year', flat=True)`

Answer (score 1):

`date()` is a method of `datetime`, use

```
blog_years=[]
for entry in blog_entries:
    if entry.date.date().year not in blog_years:
        blog_years.append(entry.date.date().year)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation -- that .date() is a method I have to call, and I needed the () on it, rather than a property that I can access.

Answer (score 1):

from django 1.10 it has become very simple

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear 

blog_years= blog_entries.annotate(
      year=ExtractYear('created_on')
).values_list('year', flat=True)
blog_years = sorted(set(blog_years), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you exactly expects (it can return years without blog posts):

```
from datetime import date
from django.db.models import Min

def blog_years():
    current_year = date.today().year
    queryset = Entry.objects.annotate(Min('date')).order_by('date')
    if queryset:
        oldest_year = queryset[0].date.date().year
    else:
        oldest_year = current_year
    return range(oldest_year, current_year + 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ModelName.objects.dates('column_name', 'year')
```